# Android - Searchview can only do one search only

Tags: android, viewmodel, searchview, android-mvvm

I made a movie search feature with searchview. when I do the first search, then the data or list will appear, but when I want to search again with a new search word and then I submit, the next data or list does not appear and only displays the previous data. there is not even a reaction to finding the next data. when I go out and return to the fragment, the search will go on as before, is there a solution to this? thank you

**MovieSearchFragment**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_movie, container, false);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    searchView = view.findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    setupRecyclerView();

    return view;
}    

private void loadMovie(String search) {

    search = searchView.getQuery().toString();

    SearchMovieViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).get(SearchMovieViewModel.class);
    viewModel.init(search);
    viewModel.getSeacrhMovie().observe(this, new Observer<MovieResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(MovieResponse movieResponse) {
            if (movieResponse != null) {
                List<Movie> movies = movieResponse.getResults();
                searchMovieList.addAll(movies);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                showLoading(false);
            } else {
                showLoading(false);
                showError();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    showLoading(true);
    loadMovie(query);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
    return false;
}

private void setupRecyclerView() {
    if (adapter == null) {
        adapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), searchMovieList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

**Viewmodel**

```
public class SearchMovieViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<MovieResponse> mutableLiveData;

    public void init(String movieTitle) {
        if (mutableLiveData != null) {
            return;
        }

        Repository repository = Repository.getInstance();
        mutableLiveData = repository.getSearchMovie(BuildConfig.API_KEY, movieTitle);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<MovieResponse> getSeacrhMovie() {
       return mutableLiveData;
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
public MutableLiveData<MovieResponse> getSearchMovie(String apiKey, String movieTitle) {
    final MutableLiveData<MovieResponse> searchData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    api.getSearchMovie(BuildConfig.API_KEY, movieTitle).enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MovieResponse> call, Response<MovieResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                searchData.setValue(response.body());
            } else {
                searchData.setValue(null);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MovieResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            searchData.setValue(null);
        }
    });
    return searchData;
}
```

Comment: Try something like "recyclerView.adapter.notifyD..()" in java,  I am not sure about java, but It works in Kotlin.

Comment: okay i will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I found the problem in my repository and then I replaced it with LiveData and added postValue as the recipient of the new value. Besides, I tried to put the adapter in my observer and changed a bit to the setupRecyclerView method. until finally the search feature can run properly, thanks for those who have helped

**MovieFragment**

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_movie, container, false);

    progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    searchView = view.findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            showLoading(true);
            loadMovie(query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    setupRecyclerView();

    return view;
}

private void loadMovie(String title) {
    title = searchView.getQuery().toString();

    SearchMovieViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SearchMovieViewModel.class);
    viewModel.init(title);
    viewModel.getSearchMovie().observe(this, new Observer<MovieResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(MovieResponse movieResponse) {
            if (movieResponse != null) {
                List<Movie> movieList = movieResponse.getResults();
                adapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                showLoading(false);
            } else {
                showLoading(false);
                showError();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void setupRecyclerView() {
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class SearchMovieViewModel extends ViewModel {
private LiveData<MovieResponse> movieLiveData;

public void init(String movieTitle) {
    Repository repository = Repository.getInstance();
    movieLiveData = repository.getSearchMovie(BuildConfig.API_KEY, movieTitle);
}

public LiveData<MovieResponse> getSearchMovie() {
    return movieLiveData;
}
}
```

**Repository**

```
  public LiveData<MovieResponse> getSearchMovie(String apiKey, String movieTitle) {
    final MutableLiveData<MovieResponse> searchData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    api.getSearchMovie(BuildConfig.API_KEY, movieTitle).enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MovieResponse> call, Response<MovieResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                searchData.postValue(response.body());
                searchData.setValue(response.body());
            } else {
                searchData.setValue(null);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MovieResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            searchData.setValue(null);
        }
    });
    return searchData;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your repository, where you instantiate new MutableLiveData on every call. You should observe one MutableLiveData, and you should call postValue on that MutableLiveData every time you get new response, so the observer (in Activity/Fragment) fetches new data.